# If X denotes the random variable counting your gain in rupees, then write probability distribution of X

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A fair die is tossed.

If the resulting number is even, you add $1$ to your score and get that
many rupees.

If the resulting number is odd, you add $2$ to your score and get that many
rupees.

If $X$ denotes the random variable counting your gain in rupees, then:

> Write the
>   probability distribution of $X$

Comment: What have you tried? It would be easier to get help from the community if you add what you have attempted and in what part are you facing difficulty.

Comment: Note: All three posts by this user so far have been PSQs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $N$ denotes the number of die throws and $K$ the number of odd results, then

$X = 2K + 1(N-K) = K+N$.

$K$ is binomially distributed with $p=0.5$, thus the distribution of $X$ is binomial with $p=0.5$ and shifted by $N$